How to remove images from link previews of your blog page?
Right now, I'm using the Soho theme for Blogger. Additionally, I do not want photos to appear on previews of my page on any platform. But I can't seem to discover any meta tags or other snippets to alter this design in Blogger's EDIT HTML area. Below is a preview generated by discord app.

